# How to add pagination for custom Apiview result data in DRF

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I have created a ListView in DRF 3. As database structure is complex I have written a custom query i.e. raw query to fetch the data. But as the data size is huge, it takes a lot of time to load it. So I need to implement pagination. Below is the code.

```
class SubnetList(APIView):

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        subnet_list = get_subnet_details(None)
        return Response(subnet_list, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

    def get_subnet_details(subnet_id=None):
        if subnet_id:
            subnets = Subnet.objects.filter(id=subnet_id).values()
        if not subnets:
            raise Http404    
        else:
            subnets = Subnet.objects.values()

        subnet_list = []
        subnet_option_query = ' SELECT  ' \
                              ' options_value.id as value_id,' \
                              ' options_value.content,' \
                              ' options_option.id,' \
                              ' options_option.name' \
                              ' FROM subnets_subnetoption' \
                              ' INNER JOIN subnets_subnet ON (subnets_subnetoption.subnet_id = subnets_subnet.id)' \
                              ' INNER JOIN options_value ON (subnets_subnetoption.value_id = options_value.id)' \
                              ' INNER JOIN options_option ON (options_value.option_id = options_option.id)' \
                              ' INNER JOIN options_scope ON (options_option.scope_id = options_scope.id)' \
                              ' WHERE subnets_subnetoption.subnet_id = %s '

        try:
            for subnet in subnets:
                subnet_dictionary = collections.OrderedDict()
                subnet_dictionary['subnet_id'] = str(subnet['id'])
                subnet_dictionary['name'] = str(subnet['name'])
                subnet_dictionary['base_address'] = str(subnet['base_address'])
                subnet_dictionary['bcast_address'] = str(subnet['bcast_address'])
                subnet_dictionary['bits'] = str(subnet['bits'])
                subnet_dictionary['begin'] = str(subnet['base_address'])
                subnet_dictionary['end'] = str(subnet['bcast_address'])
                subnet_dictionary['parent_id'] = str(subnet['parent_id'])
                subnet_dictionary['vlan_common_name'] = str(subnet['vlan_common_name'])
                subnet_dictionary['admin'] = str(subnet['admin'])
                subnet_dictionary['responsible'] = str(subnet['responsible'])
                subnet_dictionary['comments'] = str(subnet['comments'])

                super_subnet = 'True' if subnet['is_physical'] else 'False'
                subnet_dictionary['is_physical'] = super_subnet
                options = SubnetOption.objects.raw(subnet_option_query % (subnet['id']))

                physical_attributes = collections.OrderedDict()
                range_attributes = collections.OrderedDict()
                gatewaydevice_attributes = collections.OrderedDict()
                securityzone_attributes = collections.OrderedDict()
                for option in options:
                    if option.name.lower() == 'provider':
                        subnet_dictionary['provider'] = str(option.value_id)
                    elif option.name.lower() == 'customer':
                        subnet_dictionary['customer'] = str(option.value_id)
                    elif option.name == 'Allocated by RIPE/ARIN/APNIC':
                        subnet_dictionary['allocated_by'] = str(option.value_id)

                    if super_subnet == 'True':
                        if option.name.lower() == 'vlan usage':
                            physical_attributes['vlan_usage'] = str(option.value_id)
                        elif option.name.lower() == 'environment':
                            physical_attributes['environment'] = str(option.value_id)
                        elif option.name.lower() == 'status':
                            physical_attributes['status'] = str(option.value_id)
                        elif option.name.lower() == 'vrf':
                            physical_attributes['vrf'] = str(option.value_id)
                        elif option.name.lower() == 'dns on demand status':
                            physical_attributes['dns_on_demand_status'] = str(option.value_id)

                        dmz = 'True' if subnet['dmz'] else 'False'
                        physical_attributes['dmz'] = dmz            
        except ValueError as e:
            print(e)
            pass
        return subnet_list
```

Comment: The indentation was wrong, I tried to fix it. What's the point of returning `subnet_list`, when it is an empty list. Also calling `get_subnet_details(None)` doesn't make sense. It means a real `subnet_id`is never going to be passed, also passing `None` is not needed.

Answer (score 1):

Pass in a couple more parameters (you can make them optional if you want) - something like `page` and `pagesize`. Then use them to limit the query. For MySQL it would be something like `LIMIT (pagesize * page),page`. However, the specifics will vary depending on the database engine.

So, **use the Django ORM**. I can't say for sure without seeing the models, but I am fairly certain you can rewrite the query as a simple Django ORM query:

`SubnetOption.objects.filter(subnet=subnet['id'])`

and the various INNER JOINs should come through automagically.

Then you can use a range line `[page*pagesize:(page+1)*pagesize]` at the end of the query and Django will translate that into a LIMIT or the equivalent for your database engine.

Comment: Thanks for the reply 
BTW I have added extra parameter ?page=<no> in the url and then I am getting the same in request meta parameter. That value is used in for range line in query. Thus solved my issue :)

Answer (score -1):

First, create a file named pagination.py in your app. then copy these codes:

```
class LargeResultsSetPagination(PageNumberPagination):
    page_size = 1000
    page_size_query_param = 'page_size'
    max_page_size = 10000

class StandardResultsSetPagination(PageNumberPagination):
    page_size = 100
    page_size_query_param = 'page_size'
    max_page_size = 1000
```

After that, you can use from those classes like example below:

```
class BillingRecordsView(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Billing.objects.all()
    serializer_class = BillingRecordsSerializer
    pagination_class = LargeResultsSetPagination
```

Comment: He is using API view, not ListAPIView. This is not applicable in his case.